# Auto login the customer after registration in magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento

Is there any method or concept that when the customer register in fronted then login auto and redirect to the home page.

i wants to do the things by external (out of magento).

Answer (score 0):

In **Magento** you can use one of below approach.

***Option A:***

1. Login into magento admin area
2. Go to `System => Configuration => Customer Configuration`
3. `Create New Account Options` tab and set "No" to '`Require Emails Confirmation`' option.
4. `Login Options` and set "No" for '`Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in`' option.
5. Then open `\app\code\core\Mage\Customer\controllers\AccountController.php`

you can change it from this:

```
$session->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::helper('customer')->getAccountUrl());
```

To this:

```
$session->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::getBaseUrl());
```

***Option B:***

Create a custom module to work with "customer_login" event observer.

***Option C:***

Use the free community extension for logi redirect. You can get the idea from below one:

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customer-redirect-to-link-page-after-login-and-create-accounts-1.html